# How can I put the colpivot function in a view?

Tags: postgresql, function, view

I am using the function colpivot.sql (https://github.com/hnsl/colpivot) to convert rows into columns dynamically. I need to place the result of this query in a view in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW fun_test AS
    SELECT colpivot('_test_pivoted', 
            'select * from _test',
            array['year', 'month'], 
            array['country', 'state'], 
            '#.income', null);
    SELECT * FROM _test_pivoted;
```

When I execute the query, it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: column "colpivot" has pseudotype void
SQL state: 42P16
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: colpivot can't be used to create a View because it returns a temporary table for the particular session, and view required the static object.